# Parameter not being passed to layout-macro-def

Tags: bixby

It seems like a parameter is not being passes to a layout-macro-def, and I can't figure out why.

I've read the documentation for layouts / layout macros.

In my layout, I have something like this:

```
result-view {
  match:  dailyDeals (this) {
    from-property: inventory (inventory) // the param to pass
  }
  message {
    template  ("Wow!") {
      speech ("#{value(this)}")
    }
  }
  render {
    layout {
      section {
      ....
      value ("#{value(inventory.item)}" // e.g., a vbox text value
      ....
      layout-macro (myMacro) {param (inventory)}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a layout macro like this:

```
layout-macro-def (myMacro) {
  params {
    param (inventory) {
      type (inventory)
      max (Many) 

    }
  }
  content {
    ....
    value ("#{value(inventory.item)}" // e.g., a vbox text value
    .....
   }
}
```

I can access `inventory` values from within the layout just fine (e.g., `inventory.item`.) However, it seems that inventory isn't being passed (or is empty?) when it gets to the macro, because `inventory.item` won't show up in the layout from myMacro.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide us with information on the nature of `dailyDeals` and `inventory`? Is `inventory` a property of the `dailyDeals` concept?

Comment: Any chance you can share this source code? You can also file an issue through the IDE.

Comment: @Ameya: Answered below. But it case it helps others: dailyDeals is a property of inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add the expression key to the param.
Try this:

```
 render {
    layout {
      section {
      ....
      value ("#{value(inventory.item)}" // e.g., a vbox text value
      ....
      layout-macro (myMacro) {param (inventory) {expression (inventory)} }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.  The sum total of documentation on this is: "Expression that must evaluate to an appropriate argument." What does ````expression```` do, exactly?

Comment: With the expression(...) you give the concept name which will be passed from the layout to the layout-macro .
So it's basically a mapping from the Layout ( using expression(...) ) to the layout-macro (using param(...) )